# What if Nobody Will Run a Full Node?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network

As I understand from this blog: https://www.tangleblog.com/2017/06/27/incentive-run-fullnode-iota/
There's an incentive for companies and in some cases people to run a full node.

But what can happen if nobody runs a full node, or only a very small portion of the users?
How can IOTA guarantee that the network will have enough full nodes?

Comment: Many IoT devices across the world will become a full-node, others devices that don't have the full-node's system requirement will become [swarm-nodes](https://blog.iota.org/iota-development-roadmap-74741f37ed01#650e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody runs a full node, nobody can access the IOTA network and use it. 
If only a few full nodes are present and many users which connect with them, these are overloaded (like a DDoS). Also the network would be more vulnerable.

IOTA can`t guarantee that the network will have enough full nodes, alike Bitcoin or any other crypto-currency.
Theoretical the IOTA Foundation could run some full nodes, but this is not the sense and purpose of a decentralized crypto-currency.